# verificação de nulo em substring

Tags: sql-server

Preciso ter uma verificação caso não tenha uma comparação com algum valor nulo, não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar está condição.

```
AND SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LE.DTHREMPRESTIMO,103) AS VARCHAR),4,2) = CAST(SUBSTRING('11/2018',1,2)AS VARCHAR)
AND SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),LE.DTHREMPRESTIMO,103) AS VARCHAR),7,4) = CAST(SUBSTRING('11/2018',4,4)AS VARCHAR)
```

Isso é uma condição do `WHERE`. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Algo do tipo: `LE.DTHREMPRESTIMO NOT NULL AND`?

Comment: tentei AND LE.DTHREMPRESTIMO IS NOT NULL, não funcionou para o meu caso..

Comment: Mas então o que está resultando em NULL? Talvez não seja este campo?

Comment: estava colocando no lugar errado, ainda sou novo e tava dificil kkk quer colocar como resposta para eu confirmar ela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND LE.DTHREMPRESTIMO IS NOT NULL
```